# MS-Access front-end does not recognise dates from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, datetime, date

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with an Access front-end. My problem is that Access does not recognise SQL Server's dates as they are in a different format.

SQL Server-s format is `YYYY-MM-DD`
Access' format is `DD-MM-YYYY`

When the date is displayed in a text-box, it is displayed as a string (without the little calendar icon next to it).
Is there anyway I can configure my Access front-end so that it recognises SQL Server's dates?

Cheers.

Comment: It feels to me like the values in SQL Server are stored in a string format. Can you verify that they are stored in actual date column?

Comment: Yeah, they are stored as date, and yeah it is a linked table :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing the dates in SQL server as the data type “Date” or “Date2” try changing them to “DateTime” I had this problem linking data from SQL server 2008R2 to access 97, access did not see it as a date and treated it like text

Comment: Another thing that isn't involved here is if you upsize Access data to SQL Server using SQL Server Migration Assistant, any date column with values that are invalid in SQL Server will be created in SQL Server as text (!!!). SSMA allows you to run a report before the upsizing, so it will flag the tables that have invalid dates (though it won't tell you which fields). I'm just throwing this in for completeness because I encountered it just in the last 10 days.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Access 2010... I had to explicitly cast the date using CDate([Date]) in the SQL view

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access does move the dates over as a Date format. The problem the user has encountered is with a Driver. Microsoft has a new DLL that must be put on a client workstation (or server in the case of Citrix). 
Once that is done, all the dates in MS Access will work properly.
My lastest experience with Access 2010 was exactly the same as Access 2003. It required a DLL.
From there, investigate using a DNS-Less connection string.

Comment: Do you have the link where I can download this DLL ?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to this, thanks everyone for your input.

I'm also developing an Access UI for a SQL Server backend (Access 2010/SQL Server 2014) and just encountered this problem.  The Date datatype takes 3 bytes of storage, and since I didn't need a time component, that's what I wanted.  Personally I'm using SmallDateTime, it takes 4 bytes compared to DateTime's 8.  There's also DateTime2 that takes 6-8 bytes.

I created a four field table using each of the date datatypes to experiment with input formats, I think SmallDateTime will do the trick for me.