# Date stored as a string in sql server when upsized from access 2007

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2007

When I upsize from Access2007 to SQL Server 2008, I have few issues...

**1. text to nvarchar(255)**

fields with text data type in Access are automatically converted to nvarchar(255)(`I have unicode data`) in sql server, but in reality the column-length is not that big so can I change the data type to nvarchar(55) or varchar(100)?  Will there be any problem?

**2. Date stored as text**

Some tables throwed an error when tried to upsize because of the date column(`mm/dd/yyyy`), what I did is I changed the `date/time` column data type to `text` datatype in access, then the upsizing was successful, it converted to `nvarchar(255)` in sql server. I have converted `nvarchar` data type to `date` data type in sql server, but that does not show me a calendar symbol in access front-end. How to get a calendar symbol in the date field in my access front end?

[I have tried the solution given in this link, but it did not work...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702089/ms-access-front-end-does-not-recognise-dates-from-sql-server) Please give me some suggestions

Comment: You have learned why you should NEVER use the upsize wizard, it makes bad choices. You should design the SQL tables your self first and the import the data.

Comment: @HLGEM Please elaborate...Is upsizing a very bad choice, but I didn't have any other option. For me the SQL Server Import and Export wizard never worked...and I can't use the `open data source` command, as the sql server hosted on my company does not support it. How else do you suggest me to transfer the data?

Comment: I would use SSIS. But since you already used the wizard, go thorugh and fix the datatypes

Answer (score 0):

`text` in sql server is deprecated, use `nvarchar` if you need to store unicode (multi lang support).  Otherwise you can use `varchar`.

Comment: will it be any issue(`like consuming more memory`) in the future if I leave as it is (nvarchar(255))?