# From Access 2002 to Access 2010 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on this Access 2002 database.  It uses linked servers to SQL Server 2008.  I am having a problem where in load of the main form it does a DLookup and looks at a date.

```
EndDate = Nz(DLookup("End_Date", "Employee", "EmpID= " & EmpID & " AND End_Date IS NOT NULL AND End_Date < #" & Now & "#"), "")
```

Now this works fine in Access 2002, but in Access 2010 I get the:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Here's the kicker though, it works in Access 2010 for one user: myself.  No other users does it work for and also other installations with Windows 7 and the Access 2010 Runtime work fine.  On the same machine the MDB works correctly also.  If I replace the Pound signs with single quotes like in SQL Server it runs fine on the 2010 machine but no longer works on 2002 (duh).

It's just been wracking my brain and normally I have been able to get it to work by uninstalling all of Office and then reinstalling and making sure the SP1 for the Access Runtime was installed last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of transforming the value of `Now()` to a string in your `DLookup`, just let the db engine determine `Now()` for itself.

```
EndDate = Nz(DLookup("End_Date", "Employee", _
"EmpID= " & EmpID & " AND End_Date IS NOT NULL AND End_Date < Now()"), "")
```

That approach does not depend on a conversion between Date/Time and string and back again, so will avoid the problem you reported.

If you want to examine how the original `DLookup` gave different results, try something like this on the different machines:

```
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "EmpID= " & EmpID & " AND End_Date IS NOT NULL" & _
    " AND End_Date < #" & Now & "#"
Debug.Print "strCriteria: " & strCriteria
EndDate = Nz(DLookup("End_Date", "Employee", strCriteria), "")
```

After running that code, go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) and inspect the value of `strCriteria`.

Comment: This did get me past my initial problem.  But then I get an error about format.  I have a feeling the references are getting screwed up.  It is an MDE that I am trying to run and it is the Access 2010 Runtime on a terminal server.  What is interesting again is that it works under my profile, on the terminal server, but no one else's profile.  Could references be linked back to a profile somehow?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying you get still get an error with `" AND End_Date < Now()"`?  There should not be a format issue there because the db engine will get a Date/Time value when it evaluates `Now()`.  And a Date/Time value is a double precision float which is independent of any formatting issues.

Comment: If that was the initial issue and is now resolved, please provide details about the current issue.  Sorry, I'm lost here.  :-(

Comment: Haha no problem.  Really I think the issue is related to profiles somehow.  For some reason I can load the same MDE with one profile on this Windows 2008 Terminal server just fine.  But with another user login/profile it gives a new error about using the Format() command which is typically related to broken references.

Comment: What I don't get is it works for one profile but not another, the same piece of code and the same Access version

Comment: If you suspect the problem is due to a broken reference, you can add a procedure to iterate through the `References` collection and check the `IsBroken` property for each of them.  Submit a question about this if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the type of date / time field that you are using in SQL Server may cause problems, which could explain the difference between versions.

> Access 2010 provides limited support for four new date/time data types
>   that were added in SQL Server 2008:
>
> TIME 
>   DATE 
>   DATETIME2 
>   DATETIMEOFFSET

-- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-an-access-project-HA010341589.aspx#_Toc257281378

> If you are storing the dates in SQL server as the data type “Date” or
>   “Date2” try changing them to “DateTime” I had this problem linking
>   data from SQL server 2008R2 to access 97, access did not see it as a
>   date and treated it like text

-- [MS-Access front-end does not recognise dates from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702089/ms-access-front-end-does-not-recognise-dates-from-sql-server)

As an aside, there is no need for `End_Date IS NOT NULL`, once you add another criterion, null values will be excluded unless you specifically include them.