# Display all datetime fields within a database with multiple table before a certain date

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am looking to create a bit of VBA code which looks through my linked tables (to an SQL Server) and outputs a list of any fields which are datetime and have a date under the year 1990.

I think i'll need two for each loops like so

```
For Each table in currentDB.TableDefs

    For Each field in table.fields

        If field.type = datetime and field.value < '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
            debug.print table.name, field.name and field.value.
        End IF

    Next
Next
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you wanted the value to be less than 1900?  Just checking that that isn't the issue

Comment: Yes, Im looking for any dates in the database before 1990

Comment: the code is looking for dates earlier than 1900 not 1990.  Most likely that isn't your issue

Comment: sorry, your right....1900! My bad typo

Answer (score 1):

You already have two loops! You seem to have done it right. Does it not work?

Comment: I think that it is two loops I require, but its just how I do it is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

VBA Solution

Basically loops through every field on every table looking for a DateTime field type (integer value of 8 - http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html).  Once if finds a DateTime field, run a query and see if it returned any records.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim t As TableDef
Dim f As Field
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each t In db.TableDefs
    For Each f In t.Fields
        If f.Type = 8 Then

            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & f.Name & " FROM " & t.Name & " WHERE " & f.Name & " < #1/1/1990 12:00:00 PM#;")
            If rs.EOF = False Then
                Debug.Print t.Name, f.Name, rs.Fields(f.Name)
            End If
            rs.Close

        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, although it is giving me a type mismatch every-time I run it at the 'For Each f In t.Fields' line. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Odd, it's working on my end.  Try declaring f without a type "Dim f"

Comment: I have linked tables as well as native tables in Ms Access... I tried to remove the type and it is giving me a type mis match over the SQL statement.... I have this saved in a module, is that ok to run it from that?

Comment: Running from a module is OK.  Can you try just running the code on a single native table?  I ran it on my linked tables (DB2) and it worked but perhaps something to do with your linked tables date format.

Comment: Maybe, were you able to test it only on a single native table?  Also what kind of tables are you linking to (non-Access ones)?

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the 'f' variable. This works for the tables, although the field variables are causing issues, how else do you think i could define the fields in this code?

Comment: I'm thinking it is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702089/ms-access-front-end-does-not-recognise-dates-from-sql-server.  Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If your your field type is DateTime then you only have to use year function()

```
If year(field.value) > 1900 Then

    'codes here

End If
```

In VB you can do like this

```
Dim dBirth as Date

For x as Integer = 0 to MyTable.rows.Count-1
   dBirth = MyTable.Rows(x).Item("birthdate")
   If dBirth > 1990 Then

       'codes here  

   End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that will make the code cleaner....although i'm still not sure of how to loop around all the tables in the database and pull out the relevant datetime fields which contain a date before 1990. any ideas?

Comment: could you give me another example in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this stored procedure: It takes the year as input parameter.
It returns columns (with their tables name) that have values under the inputted year.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAllDateColumns] @startDateYear [INT]
AS
  BEGIN
      SET nocount ON;
      -- --------------- 
      DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @col_name VARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
      DECLARE @count INT
      -- ---------------
      DECLARE @ResultArray TABLE
        (
           table_name NVARCHAR(100),
           col_name   VARCHAR(100)
        )
      -- ----------------
      DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ( SCH.name + '.' + TAB.name )AS tablename,
               COL.name                     AS colname
        FROM   sys.schemas SCH,
               sys.tables TAB,
               sys.columns COL,
               sys.types TYP
        WHERE  COL.system_type_id = TYP.system_type_id
               AND TAB.object_id = COL.object_id
               AND SCH.schema_id = TAB.schema_id
               AND TYP.name IN ( 'datetime', 'date' );

      OPEN table_cursor
      FETCH next FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name, @col_name
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM '
                              + @table_name + ' WHERE  datepart(year,' +
                              + @col_name + ' ) < '
                              + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @startDateYear)
            EXECUTE Sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@cnt int OUTPUT', @cnt=@count output
            IF @count >= 1
              BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO @ResultArray(table_name, col_name)VALUES (@table_name,@col_name)
              END
            FETCH next FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name, @col_name
        END
      CLOSE table_cursor
      DEALLOCATE table_cursor
      --Return result
      SELECT * FROM   @ResultArray
  END
```

To call this procedure from SQL Server, all you have to do is to execute this query:

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetAllDateColumns] @startDateYear = 2003
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL terms you need a cursor to run through all table/date-column pairs and find smallest date value in each column. You can insert your results in a temporary table to analyse them as needed.

Sorry that this is not VBA, but VBA will not do any work, but just relay SQL commands.
So if you can access db only via VBA (for any reason), send this command, and read output from last `select` statement as normal.

```
IF exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#Temp_results%') DROP TABLE #Temp_results
create table #Temp_results (
    table_name varchar (50) null,
    column_name varchar (50) null,
    Min_Date datetime null
)
GO

declare @sql varchar (max), @tab varchar (50), @col varchar (50)
declare _cur insensitive cursor for

    select top 2 c.name as table_name, a.name as column_name
    from sys.columns a
    join sys.types b on a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id
    join sys.tables c on a.object_id = c.object_id
    where b.name like 'date%' or b.name = 'timestamp%'
    and c.type = 'U'

open _cur
fetch next from _cur into @tab, @col    
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 
    select @sql ='INSERT INTO #Temp_results select ''' + @tab + ''', ''' + @col + ''', (select min([' + @col + ']) from [' + @tab + '])'

    --select @sql  /* This is used to debug d-sql. Comment out next statement. Copy and execute SQL code. */

    exec (@sql)

fetch next from _cur into @tab, @col    
end 

close _cur
deallocate _cur
GO

select table_name,  column_name, Min_Date, 
case 
 when Min_Date < '1900-01-01' then 'Very old date'
 when Min_Date < '1990-01-01' then 'Just an old date'
 else 'OK' 
end How_Old_Date_Is

from #Temp_results
GO
```