# Converting Access application with linked tables to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2014

We have an Access application that uses SQL Server 2000 ODBC DSNless linked tables. We are upgrading to SQL Server 2014 and I am changing from using the connection string

```
ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;..." to ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;...
```

The application works after the conversion except when I try to run a query with this where clause it fails on this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE [Expiration Date] < #8/17/2015#
```

The error message is

> ODBC call failed: Conversion failed when converting date an/or time from character string. (#241)

Update: the queries with where clauses that used to work are access queries that are based off a query that queries the SQL Server database.

Comment: the meaning of your date literals depends on the language. Is it `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`? that's why it is recommended to use literal formats that don't depend on the language. In your case you could have SQL Server 2000 configured as US english and new SQL Server 2014 configured as UK english. If SQL Server expects `DD/MM/YYYY`, then it would fail to convert `8/17/2015`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not use MS Access date format especially with the use of `#`. [Date functions in SQL Server](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) are formatted as such:

- DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD
- DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
- SMALLDATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
- TIMESTAMP - format: a unique number

Also, MS Access's JET/ACE SQL Engine is a different SQL dialect than SQL Server so every query statement may not be compatiable. This is true if you migrate SQL Server to Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, db2 and still others.

Comment: I realize that # is for formatting Access dates.  What I am trying to figure out is why it worked with the SQL 2000 driver but does not work with SQL 2014.  I want to avoid having to change a lot of queries and code.

Comment: There can be many reasons why between 14 years of software releases in addition to MS Access and Windows upgrading: DLLs, Registry Keys, Drivers, 32-bit/64-bit issues, and more. However, here is a related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702089/ms-access-front-end-does-not-recognise-dates-from-sql-server). Perhaps changing your date type in SQL Server might work. Also, check this informative [piece](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566542/Date-and-Time-Data-Types-and-Functions-SQL-Server#12) about the date/time types changes across MSSQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

If the Column Format in SQL Server is DateTime and not DateTime2 then try the below

```
 WHERE Format([Expiration Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy") < Format(#8/17/2015#,"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Or

```
Datediff("d",Format([Expiration Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy"), Format(#8/17/2015#,"dd-mmm-yyyy")) < 0
```